# Sorting a dictionary in python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python: Sort a dictionary by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/python-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

I need to sort by values a original dictionary on a descending order.
As **keys** I have numbers and as **values** I have some date and time (string).
This means I have:

```
{1: '2011-09-25 16:28:18', 2: '2011-09-25 16:28:19', 3: '2011-09-25 16:28:13', 4: '2011-09-25 16:28:25'}
```

And I want to have:

```
{4: '2011-09-25 16:28:25', 2: '2011-09-25 16:28:19', 1: '2011-09-25 16:28:18', 3: '2011-09-25 16:28:13'}
```

Please, look at the times (value). I want to sort the times on a descending order. This means, the most recent time first.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import operator
x = { 1: '2011-09-25 16:28:18',
      2: '2011-09-25 16:28:19',
      3: '2011-09-25 16:28:13',
      4: '2011-09-25 16:28:25',
      }
sorted_x = sorted(x.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

print(sorted_x)
```

This results in a list of (key, value) tuples:

```
[(4, '2011-09-25 16:28:25'),
 (2, '2011-09-25 16:28:19'),
 (1, '2011-09-25 16:28:18'),
 (3, '2011-09-25 16:28:13')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Python builtin `dict` dictionaries aren't ordered, so you cannot do that, you need a different container.

With Python 3.1 or 2.7 you can use [collections.OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict). For earlier version see this [recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576693/).

Comment: Well, but I can take this dictionary and order it by putting it on a new dictionary or something? This would be a great method. I dont care using a different container. I just dont know how to do it :/

Comment: OrderedDict is ordered on keys not values. You need to explicitly sort it by value

Comment: Ordered != sorted. One can use the orderedness to make it sorted, but maintaining this in moderately complex. If you just need (key, value) pairs in sorted (regardless on what) order once in a while, it may be easier to just use `sorted` and `.iteritems`.

Comment: @David: there is an example for that in the linked manual. but he still didn't tell use whether is python 2 or 3..