# sort by actual values in a dictionary python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I am having trouble in sorting dictionary. I am using the below code to sort them

```
sorted_x = sorted(x.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

but the problem is the sort is not done by actual values..

```
asdl 1
testin 42345
alpha 49
```

Ref: [Sorting a dictionary in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546170/sorting-a-dictionary-in-python)

I need the items sorted like below

```
asdl 1
alpha 49
testin 42345
```

Comment: is it list of dictonaries

Comment: Is your key a string or a integer?

Comment: {'alpha': '49', 'asdl': '1', 'testin': '42345'} is the dict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior the you are experiencing is due to the type of the compared variable. In order to solve it, cast it to `Integer`.

```
orted(x.iteritems(), key=lambda x: int(x[1]))
```

The final result will be:

```
[('asdl', '1'), ('alpha', '49'), ('testin', '42345')]
```

Comment: Yes, this works. But when I update the dict am doing by x.update({line.split()[0]:line.split()[1]}). By default it will take it as string?

Comment: Yes, it will. Since you are splitting a `String`, the result will be a `String`. But you can cast it to `Integer` by calling `int()` if you are sure the returned value will always be an `Integer`.